# Incorrect Entry Date

Tags: entry-date

Using the basic channel entries tag, entries made in Feb of 2015 are all showing the same entry date even though they are set to different dates.

```
<ul class="blog-list">
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="blog"
        orderby="date"
        sort="desc"
        dynamic="no"
        show_future_entries="yes"
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
    }

        <li>

                <h4>{entry_date format="%F %n, %Y"}</h4>
                <p>{title}</p>

    </li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

I am running EE 2.8.1.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date format is incorrect.

Please check https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html.

Your format there provides (%F, long month) Feburary (%n, month without leading zeros) 2 (%Y, four digit year) 2015. So yes, February is always the 2nd month, and the year isn't going to change during that month.

I think you want

```
<h4>{entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"}</h4>
```

on that line.

Comment: It always ends up being a stupid oversight! Thank you!